# Start With in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I tried to take the text after the word 'Chapeau' in this web site : https://www.guidedeschampignons.com/produit/agaric-auguste/

I get there with XPATH :

```
Chapeau = Chapeaux.append((driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/p[3]')).text)
```

But I want to take the text with a Star With because in fonction of the mushroom type the line is not always at the same place.

I tried that :

```
Chapeau = Chapeaux.append((driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//div[starts-with(., 'CHAPEAU')]"))).text)
```

and I tried 'br' and 'strong' in place of div in my code but I can't find the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
//body//div[@class='uncont']//div/p[strong[contains(text(), 'CHAPEAU')]]
```

This is a more flexible and robust selector.

Explanation: Get me the `div` element with class 'uncont' that has a `div` that contains a `p` element that contains a `strong` element with text 'CHAPEAU'.

Comment: I don't understand this code but I tried and finaly I have juste the ':' not the text following this ':'.

Comment: I added an explanation and changed xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'CHAPEAU')]//preceding::p[1]//following::p
```

Comment: Rather than offering to explain the xpath in the answer, would you just add the explanation anyway? Answers are best written for a wide future audience, rather than just the question author.